# Python - Aggregate on week of the month basis and compare

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, aggregate

I am working on a small csv data set where the values are indexed as per Week of the Month occurrence. What I want is to aggregate all of the weeks in sequence, barring the current week or the last column, to compute weekly average of the remaining data (average for ...10/1 + 11/1 + 12/1.. to get week 1 data).

The data is available in this format:

```
char 2019/11/1 2019/11/2 2019/11/3 2019/11/4 2019/11/5 2019/12/1 2019/12/2 2019/12/3 2019/12/4 2019/12/5 2020/1/1
A    1477      1577      1401      773       310       1401      1464      1417      909       712 289   
B    1684      1485      1220      894       297       1618      1453      1335      920       772 275
C    37        10        1         3         6         17        6         6         3         2    1
D    2041      1883      1302      1136      376       2175      1729      1167      960       745  278
E    6142      5991      5499      3883      1036      4949      6187      5760      3974      2339 826
F    842       846       684       462       140       789       802       134       386       251  94
```

This column (2020/1/1) shall later be used to compare with the mean of all aggregate values from week one. The desired output is something like this:

```
char    W1      W2      W3      W4      W5      2020/1/1
A       1439    1520.5  1409    841     511     289
B       1651    1469    1277.5  907     534.5   275
C       27      8       3.5     3       4       1
D       2108    1806    1234.5  1048    560.5   278
E       5545.5  6089    5629.5  3928.5  1687.5  826
F       815.5   824     409     424     195.5   94
```

Is it possible to use rolling or resample in such a case? Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive you need [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by weeks:

```
df = df.set_index(['char', '2020/1/1'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y/%m/%d')

df = df.resample('W', axis=1).mean()
print (df)
                2019-11-03  2019-11-10  2019-11-17  2019-11-24  2019-12-01  \
char 2020/1/1                                                                
A    289       1485.000000       541.5         NaN         NaN      1401.0   
B    275       1463.000000       595.5         NaN         NaN      1618.0   
C    1           16.000000         4.5         NaN         NaN        17.0   
D    278       1742.000000       756.0         NaN         NaN      2175.0   
E    826       5877.333333      2459.5         NaN         NaN      4949.0   
F    94         790.666667       301.0         NaN         NaN       789.0   

               2019-12-08  
char 2020/1/1              
A    289          1125.50  
B    275          1120.00  
C    1               4.25  
D    278          1150.25  
E    826          4565.00  
F    94            393.25
```

EDIT: If want grouping first 7 days per each month to separate groups use:

```
df = df.set_index(['char', '2020/1/1'])
c = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y/%m/%d')
df.columns = [f'{y}/{m}/W{w}' for w,m,y in zip((c.day - 1) // 7 + 1,c.month, c.year)]
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).mean()
print (df)
               2019/11/W1  2019/12/W1
char 2020/1/1                        
A    289           1107.6      1180.6
B    275           1116.0      1219.6
C    1               11.4         6.8
D    278           1347.6      1355.2
E    826           4510.2      4641.8
F    94             594.8       472.4
```

EDIT1: For grouping dy years and days use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['char', '2020/1/1'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%Y/%m/%d').strftime('%d-%Y')

df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).mean()
print (df)
               01-2019  02-2019  03-2019  04-2019  05-2019
char 2020/1/1                                             
A    289        1439.0   1520.5   1409.0    841.0    511.0
B    275        1651.0   1469.0   1277.5    907.0    534.5
C    1            27.0      8.0      3.5      3.0      4.0
D    278        2108.0   1806.0   1234.5   1048.0    560.5
E    826        5545.5   6089.0   5629.5   3928.5   1687.5
F    94          815.5    824.0    409.0    424.0    195.5
```

Comment: nice, my solution does almost same but doesnt reindex for missing weeks

Comment: @jezrael resampling on w will be under weekly frequency. What I have in my inputs are the week of the months, so 2019/11/3 means data value from date range 2019/11/14 to 2019/11/21, 2019/12/5 will cover 2019/12/28 to 2019/12/31.

Comment: @jezrael Week 1 of Nov has value of 1477 and Week 1 of Dec has 1401, so the average for week 1 should be 1439. Currently it's 1485.

Comment: @PukarAcharya - So you need grouping by days and years without months? Answer was edited.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `groupby`:

```
m= df.set_index(['char', '2020/1/1']).rename(columns=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
m.groupby(m.columns.week,axis=1).mean().add_prefix('W_').reset_index()
```

---

```
  char  2020/1/1         W_44    W_45    W_48     W_49
0    A       289  1485.000000   541.5  1401.0  1125.50
1    B       275  1463.000000   595.5  1618.0  1120.00
2    C         1    16.000000     4.5    17.0     4.25
3    D       278  1742.000000   756.0  2175.0  1150.25
4    E       826  5877.333333  2459.5  4949.0  4565.00
5    F        94   790.666667   301.0   789.0   393.25
```

Comment: Actually resampling directly with respect to w doesn't produce the output I am looking for. The date columns here are indexed as per week of the month basis, so 1-28 days will be grouped under week 1-4 respectively, each having 7 days bar, and remaining days of the month will be grouped under week 5. In my required output, W1 is the mean of 2019/11/1(first week of Nov) and 2019/12/1(first week of Dec), W5 is of 2011/11/5(fifth week of Nov) and 2011/12/5 (5th week of Dec).